# Вывод фото в шаблоне. One to Many

Tags: python, django

Не получается вывести несколько img в одном посте. 
**models.py**

```
class NewsImage(models.Model):
    images = models.FileField('Фото', upload_to=get_upload_md_name, blank=True)
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='news')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py** Добавляю 
`images = NewsImage.objects.filter()`

но в шаблоне **{% for images in images %}** Выводит вообще все картинки не зависимо к какому посту они относятся

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось само собой.

```
images = NewsImage.objects.filter(news=post)
```